# AFJSONRequestOperation array populates but cannot NSLog contents outside of success block

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, afnetworking

[The following code is taken from this tutorial](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/ios-sdk_afnetworking/)

I've used this snippet before but I never noticed this issue before. NSLog of the array contents prints in a delegate method but not in the viewDidLoad outside of the success block. I require a way to save the JSON data into an array for use elsewhere in the code. I should also add that I'm not using UITableView to display my data. What am I missing or how can I accomplish this?

**This does not print the JSON content thought it does populate the array:**

```
#import "AFNetworking.h"
...
- (void)viewDidLoad {
...

self.movies = [[NSArray alloc] init];
NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"http://itunes.apple.com/search?term=harry&country=us&entity=movie"];
NSURLRequest *request = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];

AFJSONRequestOperation *operation = [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON) {
        self.movies = [JSON objectForKey:@"results"];
        [self.activityIndicatorView stopAnimating];
        [self.tableView setHidden:NO];
        [self.tableView reloadData];

    } failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error, id JSON) {
        NSLog(@"Request Failed with Error: %@, %@", error, error.userInfo);
    }];

    [operation start];

    NSLog(@"self.movies %@",self.movies); // does not print
...
}
```

**This does print the JSON content:** I've only used numberOfRowsInSection as a separate location for the NSLog statement.

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    if (self.movies && self.movies.count) {
        NSLog(@"self.movies %@",self.movies); // prints
...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You are kicking off an asynch operation and then immediately trying to print out the contents. Move your first `NSLog` statement into the success block.

```
AFJSONRequestOperation *operation = [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON) {
    //the following lines of code execute after the response arrives
    self.movies = [JSON objectForKey:@"results"];
    NSLog(@"self.movies %@",self.movies);
} failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error, id JSON) {
    NSLog(@"Request Failed with Error: %@, %@", error, error.userInfo);
}];
[operation start];
//this line of code executes directly after the request is made, 
//and the response hasn't arrived yet
NSLog(@"I probably don't have the response yet");
```

Comment: Thank you but I was already aware that this would work. However, I'm not able to use the contents of the array outside of the block statement but still within viewDidLoad.

Comment: This is the correct answer. `self.movies` hasn't been populated when `NSLog` is called. The reason it prints in `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` is because you're triggering this method in your success block with `reloadData` so `self.movies` will have been assigned.

Comment: Yes, but what about the line commented as `// does not print`? I won't be using a `UITableView` in my actual project. This example is from a guide. Surely there must be a way to use `AFJSONRequestOperation` and an array without `UITableView`.

Comment: The operation is *asynchronous* which means you can simply print out the response *after it arrives*. Asynchronous means it runs in a separate thread so you have to wait for the response prior to being able to do anything with the response. You are currently trying to print out the response before it even arrives.